Mock "aws_lambda_powertools.parameters"
How can I mock AWS parameter store "New_URL" with value "/Good"
mockeyPatch.setattr(
         "aws_lambda_powertools.utilities.parameters.get_parameter",
         lambda parameter_name: "/Good" if parameter_name == "NEW_URL" else ""
     )

